# VS 2015 Localdb error 26

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014-localdb

I am trying to get the attached program to work, but I get an error 26 cannot find server for the local db. This is a straight MSDN example. I can open the localdb with SSMS 2014, part of the sql express installation. Also in VS 2015 I can create a database connection to the localdb with (localdb)\mssqllocaldb.
The EF is version 6 (latest downloaded with NuGet).I have no idea why this is not working.

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BloggingContext())
            {
                // Create and save a new Blog 
                Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();

                var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                var query = from b in db.Blogs
                            orderby b.Name
                            select b;

                Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Maarten

Comment: your posted code does not contain connectionString. How anyone is supposed to help with the above code?

Comment: This is a standard example of msn. It creates the database in the background using the localdb.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link? I guess, I have followed the same link sometimes ago, but do not remember the it. It may also be helpful for others too.

Comment: The link is:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb` instead of `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`. See `\\`.

`\` is a escape character so you need to use two. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: Will try this and revert back

Answer (score 0):

did you add sql connection ?

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

`"user id=username;" +"password=pass.;server=servername;" +
 "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +"database=tablo_1; " + "connection timeout=30"`

the servername should be like this :`DESKTOP-I....\\SQL_2014;`